# GoogleFinance - Remove USD Symbol

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

Using google spreadsheets to display currency data, with USD as primary field for formula: `=LEFT(V10*GoogleFinance("currency:USDEUR"),5)`

I cannot figure out how to **remove** the the USD Symbol *($)* from not show up for the additional currencies. It makes no sense to have the **$**xxx being displayed on non-USD data.

I have tried doing `Format -> Numbers` but none of those options resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number formats are not working since the LEFT function is converting the value to text.  Does this formula work instead:

`=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(V10*GoogleFinance("currency:USDEUR"),5),"$","")`

Comment: That worked Chris. Thanks a bunch. So, "left" converts to text. Good to know. And, "substitute" is basically a "str_replace" eh - very sweet!

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the cells you want to change. Go to Format --> Number --> More Formats --> Custom number format.  Highlight the "$" and delete it (delete the quotes and dollar sign both).  Click apply.  I have attached before and after pictures.

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Hey Jen, mine did not have "$" only $ and removing it did not do any good.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't seen that before.  Glad Chris' suggestion worked out though :)